# why does flutter config for web shows like enable-web: true (Unavailable)?

Tags: flutter-web

I wanted to develop web application in flutter with the beta support. Thus, I enabled web in flutter config through CLI as below.

```
$ flutter config --enable-web
WARNING: cgroup v2 is not fully supported yet, proceeding with partial confinement
Setting "enable-web" value to "true".

You may need to restart any open editors for them to read new settings.
```

As next step in the process of development, I wanted to check if the browser is connected as device with flutter, but it's not

```
$ flutter devices
WARNING: cgroup v2 is not fully supported yet, proceeding with partial confinement
No devices detected.
```

Hence, I cross verified the flutter config, it showed the status of web enabled as

```
$ flutter config
...
Settings:
  enable-web: true (Unavailable)
```

**Why does enable-web show true, but unavailable? How can I connect web browser as device in flutter?**

Comment: Run `flutter channel`. What's the output?

Comment: flutter channel is stable. will changing to beta work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're currently on the stable channel of flutter. Flutter is only supported on beta and higher releases at the moment. You can change to beta and enable web support with:

```
flutter channel beta
flutter upgrade
flutter config --enable-web
```

[Source](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web)